# Formularios de Archivos JSP

Tags: jsp, formularios

tengo en mi formulario para recibir un fichero y lo hace bien, pero si al formulario le añado inputs type text, ya no recibo el fichero ...

Creo que el problema viene de esta línea

```
  String contentType = request.getContentType();
```

Porque recibe muchos tipos diferentes y luego no se mete en el if... pero no tengo ni idea de como coger un request.getParemeter(DEL archivo), entre paréntesis el name del  esto sí se...
Pero a la hora de  recogerlo en el JSP para que entre en el ¿¿ if ???

```
        String textarea = request.getParameter("txtarea");
        String origin = request.getParameter("txtorigin");
        String topic = request.getParameter("txttopic");

        String[] destination = request.getParameterValues("user[]");

        //---------- Upload file to server
        File file;
        int maxFileSize = 5000 * 1024;
        int maxMemSize = 5000 * 1024;
        String filePath = "c:/apache-tomcat/webapps/data/";

        String contentType = request.getContentType();

        if ((contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {

            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
            factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            upload.setSizeMax(maxFileSize);
            try {
                List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
                Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();
                out.println("<html>");
                out.println("<body>");
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    FileItem fi = (FileItem) i.next();
                    if (!fi.isFormField()) {
                        String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
                        String fileName = fi.getName();
                        boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
                        long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
                        file = new File(filePath + "yourFileName");
                        fi.write(file);
                        out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + filePath + fieldName + "<br>");
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }// end upload file
```

Answer (score 0):

**Utilizar librerías como: commons-fileupload-1.3.3 Y commons-io-2.5**
No tiene que poner el tipo de contenido, y lo que haría sería más o menos lo siguientes, todo depende de lo que usted desee:

```
    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*" %>
    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*" %>
    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*" %>
    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.*" %>
    <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>

    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <%!
              String mensaje ="";
            %>      
            <%

                FileItemFactory file_factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                /*ServletFileUpload esta clase convierte los input file a FileItem*/
                ServletFileUpload servlet_up = new ServletFileUpload(file_factory);
                /*sacando los FileItem del ServletFileUpload en una lista */
                List items = servlet_up.parseRequest(request);

                for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
                    /*FileItem representa un archivo en memoria que puede ser pasado al disco duro*/
                    FileItem item = (FileItem) items.get(i);
                    /*item.isFormField() false=input file; true=text field*/
                    if (! item.isFormField()){
                        continue;
                    }else if(item.getFieldName().equalsIgnoreCase("documento")){
                        dni_persona=Integer.parseInt(item.getString());
                    }
                 }               
                            }
                for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
                    /*FileItem representa un archivo en memoria que puede ser pasado al disco duro*/
                    FileItem item = (FileItem) items.get(i);
                    /*item.isFormField() false=input file; true=text field*/
                     if (! item.isFormField()){
                        /*cual sera la ruta al archivo en el servidor*/

                        if(item.getSize()>0){/*Si el input file archivo pesa (hay archivo) lo crea*/

                            File archivo_a_crear = new File("c\\unaruta\\"+item.getFieldName()+".pdf");
                            if(archivo_a_crear.exists())archivo_a_crear.delete();
                            item.write(archivo_a_crear);
                            /*Verificamos si el archivo ya existe*/
                            /*Creamos el archivo*/
                        }
                    } 
                }

            %>
            </script>      
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Saludos, el problema no es que se suba el archivo al servidor, el problema es que no puedo recibir los input type text con el input type file

Puedo hacer un formulario aparte para recibir los input type text y otro formulario aparte para recibir el fichero y subirlo, pero obviamente necesito integrar los 2 formularios en uno solo...

Comment: Una explicación:
1. Cuando usted manda en un formulario campos de tipo file y text, no puede utilizar `request.getParameter("txtarea");` ya que el servidor no puede interpretarlo.

2. Para capturar los campos de tipo: text, number o cualquier otro que no sea de tipo file, y además en ese mismo formulario se envían campos de tipo file, usted debe preguntar en un `if` que el tipo de parametro que llego sea `isFormField()` es decir `if(item.isFormField()){/* aqui se procesa los campos de text, number*/}`

Comment: Mire mi código, yo tengo un For para obtener los que vienen de tipo text y en otro los de tipo file. Cabe aclara que se pueden obtener ambos en un solo ciclo, pero eso lo hice por separar código que necesité.

Comment: Puse tu código y no me funcionó, cuando recojo el 
       String textarea = request.getParameter("txtarea");
        String origin = request.getParameter("txtorigin");
        String topic = request.getParameter("txttopic");
Me salen a null.

Llevo una semana dándole vueltas y probando cosas, he descubierto que si en la etiqueta form pongo enctype="multipart/form-data"
Recojo datos de type text no los recoge y me los pone a null
Pero sin enctype entonces no puedo recoger el fichero....

No sé si me entiendes...

Comment: NO SE PUEDE UTILIZAR `request.getParameter("")` CUANDO SE ENVÍAN TAMBIÉN CAMPOS DE TIPO file

Comment: Llevo 1 semana con este problema, aún no he conseguido arreglarlo.